# Showing Search Results in a Form style

Tags: python, django, listview, search

I'm developing a search tool for my web application in Django.

Right now I have this code:

On search.py:

```
import re

from django.db.models import Q

def normalize_query(query_string,
                findterms=re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"|(\S+)').findall,
                normspace=re.compile(r'\s{2,}').sub):
''' Splits the query string in invidual keywords, getting rid of unecessary spaces
    and grouping quoted words together.
    Example:

    >>> normalize_query('  some random  words "with   quotes  " and   spaces')
    ['some', 'random', 'words', 'with quotes', 'and', 'spaces']

'''
return [normspace(' ', (t[0] or t[1]).strip()) for t in findterms(query_string)] 

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):
''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
    aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

'''
query = None # Query to search for every search term        
terms = normalize_query(query_string)
for term in terms:
    or_query = None # Query to search for a given term in each field
    for field_name in search_fields:
        q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
        if or_query is None:
            or_query = q
        else:
            or_query = or_query | q
    if query is None:
        query = or_query
    else:
        query = query & or_query
return query
```

On views.py:

```
def search(request):
query_string = ''
found_entries = None
search_fields=('cedula','nombre','usuario')

if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():

    query_string = request.GET['q']

    entry_query = get_query(query_string, search_fields)

    found_entries = UsuarioFidetel.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-id')

return render_to_response('search/buscar.html', { 'query_string': query_string, 'found_entries': found_entries }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And my template, buscar.html:

```
{% if found_entries %}
            <p>You searched for "{{ query_string }}".</p>            
                <ul>
                {% for i in found_entries %}
                    <li><a href="{{ q.get_absolute_url }}">{{i.cedula}}{{i.nombre}}{{i.usuario}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% if query_string and not found_entries %}
            <p>}Este Usuario no Existe.</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>Busca el usuario por nombre, usuario o cedula y presiona Enter.</p>
        {% endif %}
```

Now, I'll need to show results like a ListView:

[image: ListView]

not like this:

[image: Search Result]

No matter what I specify on template ie: `{% for i in found_entries %}
                        <li><a href="{{ q.get_absolute_url }}">{{i.cedula}}{{i.nombre}}{{i.usuario}}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}` it keeps showing the result like that.

How can I show them like a ListView?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not the template that is being rendered. Are you using template caching perhaps - in which case have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: I mean, the search result is this template, the listview obviously don't it's an example, no didn't restart the server. Gonna try.

Comment: Right, it wasn't, you're right, the path for it was wrong, now it shows all in one line, how can I see them in one line per row?

Comment: Like: <li><a href="{{ q.get_absolute_url }}">{{i.cedula}} {{i.nombre}} {{i.usuario}}</a></li> But not in just one line

Comment: Well that's just basic HTML. You could use a `<br>` tag, for example.

Comment: Oh, yeah, right, lol thank you, I'm new into Django templating :), and I got confused sometimes, thank you very much.